# Angular 4 POST Authorization token with FormData

Tags: angular, authentication, token, image-uploading, form-data

I am trying to upload image from Angular 4.

Here is my image upload code:

```
uploadImage(file: any) {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadImage', file, file.name);

    let headers = new Headers();
    this.authService.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.authToken);
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    const ep = this.prepEndPoint('images/uploadImage');

    return this.http.post(ep, formData, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  prepEndPoint(ep) {
    if (this.isDev) {
      return ep;
    } else {
      return 'http://localhost:3000/' + ep;
    }
  }
```

And it returns error: 'Unauthorized';

I tested this token on simple post call, where I passed object as data and it worked with no problems. so my `AuthService` and server works well. Problem occurs when I am trying to post `FormData` (Image, in my case).

Any suggestions?

Comment: what was the you backend framework ??

Comment: I am using NodeJS

Comment: can you check your backend accept header "Authorization"

Comment: nodes cors configuration ,allowedHeaders: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Headers CORS header. Expects a comma-delimited string (ex: 'Content-Type,Authorization') or an array (ex: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']). If not specified, defaults to reflecting the headers specified in the request's Access-Control-Request-Headers header.